# Can I run NUnit tests from within Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, nunit

Is there an addon of some kind that will let me run and view results from inside Visual Studio? I remember there was some sort of icon with a red rocket ship on it. Any suggestions? Can't remember the name.

I don't want to use NUnit Gui if I can help it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [TestDriven.Net](http://testdriven.net/). There are other alternative test runners to the NUnit GUI too, such as [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html) and [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/).

Answer (score 2):

TestDriven.NET is the tool you are using. There are alternatives though. I've recently started using NCrunch, as it gives the same type of functionality as TestDriven, plus it gives continuous testing, which I've found really useful.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to TestDriven.Net there's always the test runners in products like CodeRush or Resharper.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper has a test runner. As a bonus you get a load of refactoring possibilities that makes you wonder how you programmed before Resharper... And no, this is not an ad, I am just a big supporter :-)